# Segmentation fault when trying to allocate memory for a string via a pointer-to-pointer function call

Tags: c, pointers, file-io, segmentation-fault, malloc

I Initiate my string and call my function like this:

```
int main() {
...
char *fileBuffer;
readFileToBuffer("/tmp/file.txt", &fileBuffer);
...
}
```

The purpose of this function is to get the contents of `file.txt` and put it into the `fileBuffer` variable. Because the content of `file.txt` is dynamic, I allocate the memory for `fileBuffer` dynamically in the `readFileToBuffer()` function like so:

```
void readFileToBuffer(char *filePath, char **fileBuffer) {
...
FILE *reqFile = fopen(filePath, "r");

fseek(reqFile, 0, SEEK_END);
long fileSize = ftell(reqFile);

fseek(reqFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

*fileBuffer = malloc(fileSize + 1);

fread(fileBuffer, fileSize, 1, reqFile);
fclose(reqFile);
...
}
```

This is causing a segmentation fault. I've googled around and this seems to be the correct way when allocating memory inside of a function.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: use valgrind and gdb, and post your debug information

Comment: Take a look at that `fread` call again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `readFileToBuffer()` code, `fileBuffer` is of type `char **` and your function is called as `readFileToBuffer("/tmp/file.txt", &fileBuffer);`

Then you have rightly allocated memory to `*fileBuffer` in `readFileToBuffer()` [*so that is gets reflected to the `fileBuffer` in `main()`*]. So, you need to pass `*fileBuffer` to `fread()` to read the contents of the files *into* the memory pointed by `*fileBuffer`.

You need to change.

```
fread(fileBuffer, fileSize, 1, reqFile);
```

to

```
fread(*fileBuffer, fileSize, 1, reqFile);  // notice the *
```

That said,

1. Always check the return value of `malloc()` for success.
2. The recommended signature for `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Comment: Nitpicking: The need to pass `*fileBuffer` (to `fread()`) does not directly arises from "*`fileBuffer` is of type `char **`*" but from the fact that (the memory to be read into) had been allocated to `*fileBuffer` (by this call `*fileBuffer = malloc(fileSize + 1);`).

Comment: @alk sir, updated the answer, can you please review whether it is proper now?